# MATLAB: How to plot solid black lines on top of transparent areas?

Tags: matlab

When I'm plotting solid black line on top of a transparent area (specified by alpha values), the plotted line isn't black as it accouts for the transparent area underneath. Is there a a way to make a specific plotted line ignore other plotted objects with alpha values and draw them 'on top'? The MATLAB version I'm using is 2013a.

Edit: My code, using patchlines (http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36953-patchline/content/patchline.m):

```
figure
hold all
red_weights = rand(100,100);

%patches with alpha value
for i= 1:50
         patchline(1:length(red_weights),red_weights(i,:),'edgecolor','b','linewidth',1,'edgealpha',0.3);
end

%following line should be solid black
plot(mean(red_weights(51:100,:)),'--k','linewidth',2);
```

Output saved as .png:
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Hi, I've added code as an edit.

Comment: Shouldn't `edgealpha` be `1`?

Comment: No, the patchlines are my transparent areas and the line drawn with the builtin plot function should be the black line.

Comment: I am getting an error message: "Undefined function or variable 'red_weights'."

Comment: Sorry, it should run now

Comment: I modified `'--k'` to `'-k'`, i.e `plot(mean(red_weights(51:100,:)),'-k','linewidth',2);`, and I can assure you, **line is pitch black on my machine**.

Comment: Can you add your result figure as an image (in png format)? Use file -> save as, select type *.png. Add the image to the question. (do it after replacing --k with -k).

Comment: I added the .png (replaced '--k' option with '-k'). Could there be a version difference? I'm using 2013a.

Comment: I tested the code in Matlab 2012b, and getting same results as yours. I guess older versions of Matlab don't handle transparency correctly.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I think I can get access to newer MATLAB versions. Can you tell me which version you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With HG2 (R2014b and above):

For Matlab versions using HG2, the MATLAB renderer works good enough with transparency (*rendered with R2016a*):

[image]

---

### Pre HG2 (R2014a and before):

For earlier Matlab release, the use of transparency in patches force Matlab to drop the `painter` renderer and use the `OpenGL` one ... which had well known issues with transparency.

Matlab 2013a gives:
[image]

but if you set the black line property `EraseMode` to `Background`, you get a more defined line:

```
hp = plot(mean(red_weights(51:100,:)),'-k','linewidth',2);
set(hp,'EraseMode','background')
```

and now (still R2013a):

[image]

As a general trick, I solved a lot of transparency/OpenGL glitches by trying different settings of the `EraseMode` porperty. It does not always work, but it can save a significant number of cases.

---

Note that this property (`EraseMode`) is becoming obsolete in the latest Matlab versions (first we got a warning, then a full blown error), so if your code have to use this trick, you may have to include a version check and branch the code depending on the running Matlab version.